# The word "rather"

Tags: word-usage

Is it true that the word "rather" is always/usually used with negative emotional sense?

That is to say, "rather good" would be wrong, wouldn't it? And I should instead use "quite good", should I?

Comment: Just an example of "rather good" - it's the name of a comedy/production company from an earlier time in the history of the internet - https://rathergood.com/about-us/

Answer (score 3):

"Rather good" is correct and fairly common in some (perhaps a little old-fashioned) British dialects.

It tends to be used as an ironic understatement to mean "very good".

> I say! You must try this wine. It's *rather* good.

Rather has other uses: to express preferences, and to indicate agreement (again dated British use). I can't think of any situation where it has a specifically negative emotional sense.

Answer (score 1):

The word "rather" is not always used negatively. Saying something is "rather good" is synonymous with saying it is "quite good".

This site gives a good summary of how the word can be used: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather

Specifically, note that using it as "in some degree" gives a similar connotation to the following word, whereas using it as "to the contrary" would give a connotation opposite to the following word.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not in any usage that I'm familiar with, in fact.

> Rather!

Is a slightly dated British English interjection indicating emphatic agreement.

> I'd rather have the red, thanks.

An indication of preference.

> That's really rather good.

Indicates that it is, indeed, good. In fact, while it literally means similar to "fairly", it tends to be used as ironic understatement.

Comment: What does *ironic understatement* mean? Do you mean to say people tend to use it to reverse the meaning of what follows and in effect say "not really" (e.g., *it's rather good* = "it's not really that good", or "it's good but it's not that good")?

Comment: Ironic understatement is to express something in a way that literally means it is "only slightly" good/bad/tasty/deadly/whatever, but to mean that it is "very" whatever. The difficulty is that some words are primarily used for ironic understatement, but some are sometimes used literally and sometimes ironically.

Comment: Are you saying *rather good* literally means "only slightly good" (in the answer you say it literally means "fairly good")? Perhaps etymologically or somehow, then leveraging irony to achieve the resultant meaning? I'm sorry, I don't understand the first sentence in your comment ("it is to express something in a way that literally means it's only slightly X, but to mean it's very X") – did you intend *but to* to mean "only to"?

Comment: The "but" could be read as "but actually"; it's a very normal way of saying it where I come from.